# configure: error: Could not link against

Tags: boost, compiler-construction, configure, rose-compiler-framework

I am trying to install Rose compiler and i am getting a configuration error 
i have removed most of the unnecessary configuration details and kept important ones.Rose compiler needs boost for installation.

```
root@bt:# ./configure --prefix=/opt/rose/rose-0.9.5a-17274/compileTree  --with-boost=/opt/boost_1_48_0/installTree --with-boost-libdir=/opt/boost_1_48_0/installTree/lib 

    .././configure: line 1846: .././scripts/shtool: No such file or directory
    .././configure: line 1846: .././scripts/shtool: No such file or directory

    checking for boostlib >= 1.36.0... yes
    In boost base macro -- Boost version being used is: 
    configure: No previously installed version of boost detected: using boost include directories with normal -I option
    Requested minimum boost version: boost_lib_version_req_major     = 1
    Requested minimum boost version: boost_lib_version_req_minor     = 36
    Requested minimum boost version: boost_lib_version_req_sub_minor = 0
    Boost version being used is: 
    rose_boost_version = 104800
    Reasonable version of Boost found!
    In ROSE/configure: ac_boost_path = /opt/boost_1_48_0/installTree
    checking for GraphViz's dot program in path... yes
    checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
    checking whether the Boost::Date_Time library is available... yes
    configure: error: Could not link against  !
```

Distribution :Backtrack 5(Ubuntu 10.04)
did anyone else get this type of  errors .
Please help
Thank you...